# Is it possible for a F# type to "inherit" from a C# class?

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I have used Haskell a bit in my days but it was a long time ago so I decided to take a look at F#. I do a lot of daily development using C, C++ and C#.

I noticed that you could expose F# types as classes in C# when compiling F# to a dll. But then I came to think. I have a few C# classes I would like to put the logic of in F# (to try it out). But a lot of the existing C# code handles a lot of objects by their base class (which is very rudimentary). Would it be possible to use that base class from C# as a base for the F# types? Or can F# only inherit from other F# types?

The reason behind this would be to keep the base class as part of the main C# project and the specific dlls (kind of like plugins based on the given contract by the base class) could be written in F#. If it can't be done I would have to add yet another F# project that contains only the base class which feels a bit overly complicated.

Comment: @inquam: I think you're missing a basic aspect of .NET, namely, that _all_ languages targeting the CLR produce the same output (IL). This means you can generally assume that if two languages expose a feature of the CLR they are interoperable in that feature as well. That probably explains why it's not explicitly stated in the docs for each language.

Comment: @inquam I guess I'm thinking (like D Stanley) why would your first course of action be asking here rather than simply trying it yourself?  I'd guess that's what ildjarn meant by "does not show any research effort."

Comment: @Daniel: Isn't "not knowing" the main driving force behind looking for an answer? If I knew that there was no difference at all between the the IL output created from a F# type and a C# class my question would have been redundant. But it's not explicitly stated anywhere in the text I read from Microsoft that this is the case. That it actually was as easy as it was is just a bonus. But we can't expect people to randomly assume and try things and find out the answer for themselves before being allowed to ask a question here. That's how I look a people asking questions at least.

Comment: @Onorio Catenacci: It wasn't my first course of action. I read a lot of documentaion at Microsoft to try to get an answer. But didn't find anything answering my question. Refining my search I have now found that I'm not the only person asking this question :)

Comment: @inquam Your question is a perfectly valid one. Some information can be too implicit in some communities. I wish I could find it still surprising that people make you defend yourself in comments longer than both your original question and the two answers provided.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

```
type SomeClass =
    inherit SomeCSharpBase
```

Here are some more details:

[Inheritance (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233225.aspx)

Comment: That easy? Wow... Are there any limitations put upon the C# class layout? It feels like since they both (F# and C# that is) compile to the same underlying language should be pretty straight forward, but one never knows.

Comment: @inquam - Read the info at the link I provided.

Comment: Think I read that page, but since it didn't mention inheriting from other languages and I didn't find any good reference about it I was unsure. Kinda nice it was this easy though. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

F# classes can inherit from .NET classes:

```
type FSharpClass() =
    inherit System.AccessViolationException()
```

Some other F# types such as records, discriminated unions cannot inherit from classes, but they can implement interfaces:

```
type FSharpRecord =
    { d : System.IDisposable }
    interface System.IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() = this.d.Dispose()
```